# Javascript - Flash messages failing to display on AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, handlebars.js, connect-flash

I am developing an app where there is a searchable database of references, and there is a management app that allows a user to edit the database. The public facing side uses Knockout JS communicating with the server via a RESTful API. The administration application uses express. Pages are rendered from templates using Handlebars. The edit view uses the same rendering code as the public view.

I am using connect-flash to send action result messages to editors. When a form is submitted to the page (used to add a new reference), then the flash messages are displayed as expected, however, for commands that are available on each item in the table view (like deleting a particular reference), I use an ajax call from a function defined in the view model. The call executes correctly and the action is performed, but the flash message is never displayed to the user. I have a custom middleware that collects the flash messages into a replacements object for the templates. When I log which messages are sent, I never see the message resulting from the delete call, so I am not just losing it on an extra refresh.

Here is the request handler that I am using:

```
var router = express.Router();
var client = solr.createClient(...);

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('refs', req.replacements);
});

// This one is submitted via an html form post, and works
router.post('/new', function (req, res, next) {

    var doc = {};

    ... // Form reading and validation code

    client.add(doc, { commitWithin: 50 }, function (err, data) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            req.flash('error', 'A problem occurred during submit.'); //works
        } else { // Success            
            req.flash('yay', 'New reference successfully added.'); //works
        }

        res.redirect(303, '/refs?rows=1&q=id%3A' + newId);
    });
});

// This one is submitted via ajax in the view model. Action works, flash doesn't
router.delete("/:id(\\d+)", function (req, res, next) {

    var id = req.params.id;
    var query = 'q=id:' + id;


    var doc = undefined;
    client.get('refs', query, function (err, obj) {
        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', 'Unable to obtain a copy of object to delete for audit log. Reference not deleted.');
            res.redirect(303, '/refs');
        } else {
            doc = obj.response.docs[0];

            client.deleteByID(id, { commitWithin: 50 }, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return req.flash('error', 'A problem occurred during delete submission.');
                } else { // Success
                    req.flash('yay', 'Reference successfully deleted.'); // Never seen
                }
            });
        }
    });

    res.redirect(303, url.format({
        pathname:"/refs",
        query:req.query,
    }));
});
```

I have tried changing the redirect to 278 to prevent the browser from handling the redirect transparently and then handling it in the success function of the ajax call, as per [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call), but that didn't help.

Here is the client-side javascript which defines the view model:

```
function RefsViewModel(qString) {
    "use strict";
    var self = this;
    self.refs = ko.observableArray();

    $.ajax({
        // This makes the call which populates self.refs with observables
    });

    self.deleteRef = function (ref) {
        $.ajax({ // Makes an AJAX query to the server for the source
            url: "/refs/" + ref.id(),
            type: "DELETE",
            error: function (jqXHR) {
                console.log("ajax error " + jqXHR.status);
                alert("Error sending delete request");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the middleware I am using to collect the flash messages:

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
function flashMessageCenter(req, res, next) {
    if(typeof req.replacements === "undefined") {
        req.replacements = {}
    }

    req.replacements.errorMessage = req.flash("error");
    req.replacements.yayMessage = req.flash("yay");
    req.replacements.infoMessage = req.flash("info");
    console.log(req.replacements);

    return next();
}
```